# i want display list in sharepoint 2013 uses js

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Following is my code:

```
 retrieveListItems('https://sustec29-public.sharepoint.com');

function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml(
    '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
    '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + 
    '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
);
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
); 
}

 function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
 var listItemInfo = '';
 var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

 while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\ngroup: ' + oListItem.get_item('group') + 
        '\ndisc: ' + oListItem.get_item('disc');
}    
        $('#message').text(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
 }
```

`

but browser views error - 
`The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.`

if i write

```
    '\ntitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('title') + '\nbody: ' + oListItem.get_item('body');
```

and rename field table`s - all ok.
But i want add own field..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add ViewFields section to your caml query:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml(
    '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name="ID"/>' + 
    '<Value Type="Number">1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + 
    '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="group" /><FieldRef Name="disk" /></ViewFields></View>'
```

EDIT:
Another way you can try to achieve this is to add Include string to your load method call:

```
clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Id, disk, group)');
```